# CSS background properties

Tags: html, css

I have this img set as background to a div. But is too big for my liking. Is there a way I could resize it in css ?

```
.portfolio {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('img/img2.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: `background-size:auto`

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can do this with two methods.
First is by giving `background-size: auto;`
Second is by giving custome size like  `background-size: 500px 200px;`

This will solve your problem. :)

Comment: Thnks ! Can I ask you something because I cant pots only in 30min . HTML scroll-behavior  does't work on Edge ?

Comment: Scroll-behaviour is not supported in edge I guess.It works only in chrome,opera and Mozilla